# Does $E(X^2Y)=E(X)\cdot E(X)\cdot E(Y)$ if $X,Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability

Given that $X,Y$ are independent, $E(XY)=E(X)\cdot E(Y)$. But $X$ is correlated with $XY$, to get $E(X\cdot XY)$ can we still use $E(X)\cdot E(X)\cdot E(Y)$

Update: looks like my original question was a bit vague. Let's consider the two scenario here:
 $E(X^2\cdot Y)$  and $E(X\cdot XY)$. Are they the same? Do they produce the same results if $X,Y$ are independent?

Comment: The title of your question the question you state in the post don't seem to match.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist How to type equations here? I someone suggested the google api,but I could find the option for math equations.

Comment: @alphabetagamma: We use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which to a large extent implements the same markup as TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: @alphabetagamma Never mind; they are the same question -- I wasn't reading the carefully enough. You can use LaTeX syntax to write equations out more clearly.

Comment: Think about using `\mathbb{E}` which is equivalent to $\mathbb{E}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. However, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then you do have that

$$ E\left(X^2Y\right)=E\left(X^2\right)E(Y) $$

Recall that, in general,

$$ E\left(X^2\right) \neq E(X)^2 $$

One case where you do have equality is when $X$ is constant (i.e. deterministic).

And to answer your edit, yes,

$$ E\left(X^2Y\right)=E(XXY)$$

Equality holds even without the expectation operator, since $X^2=X X$ by definition.

More generally, with some regularity (i.e. measurability) conditions imposed on $f$ and $g$, when $X$ and $Y$ are independent,

$$ E[f(X)g(Y)]=E[f(X)]E[g(Y)] $$